# Normalize a Vector

Tags: code-golf, math, array, geometry

To *normalize* a vector is to scale it to a length of 1 ([a unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector)), whilst keeping the direction consistent.

For example, if we wanted to normalize a vector with 3 components, **u**, we would first find its length:

> **|u| = sqrt(u<sub>x</sub><sup>2</sup> + u<sub>y</sub><sup>2</sup> + u<sub>z</sub><sup>2</sup>)**

...and then scale each component by this value to get a length 1 vector.

> **û = u ÷ |u|**

---

## The Challenge

Your task is to write a program or function which, given a non-empty list of signed integers, interprets it as a vector, and normalizes it. This should work for any number of dimensions, for example (test cases rounded to two decimal places):

```
[20]           -> [1]
[-5]           -> [-1]
[-3, 0]        -> [-1, 0]
[5.5, 6, -3.5] -> [0.62, 0.68, -0.40]
[3, 4, -5, -6] -> [0.32, 0.43, -0.54, -0.65]
[0, 0, 5, 0]   -> [0, 0, 1, 0]
```

**Rules:**

- You can assume the input list will:

  - Have at least one non-zero element
  - Only contain numbers within your language's standard floating point range
- Your output should be accurate to *at least* **two decimal places**. Returning "infinite precision" fractions / symbolic values is also allowed, if this is how your language internally stores the data.
- Submissions should be either a full program which performs I/O, or a function. Function submissions can either return a new list, or modify the given list in place.
- Builtin vector functions/classes are allowed. Additionally, if your language has a vector type which supports an arbitrary number of dimensions, you can take one of these as input.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) contest, so you should aim to achieve the shortest solution possible (in bytes).

Comment: Does it have to have at least two decimal places for every possible input (which is not possible for any standard type of floating point values) or only for the examples you provide? E.g. Steadybox's answer provides 2 decimal places of precision for all your test but he uses ints for the sum of squares which of course fails for almost all inputs (e.g. [0.1, 0.1]).

Comment: ... now we just wait for a lang with built-in norm function mapped to one char...

Comment: It should be to at least 2dp for every possible input @Christoph

Comment: @FlipTack but that rules out basically all languages because floatings points have bigger exponents than mantissa which means they do not always have enough precision to have any decimal places.

Comment: Why don't the 6 in the 4th example and the -6 in the 5th respectively normalize to 1 and -1?

Comment: @Mast because the vector _length_, not _largest component_ , needs to be scaled to 1.

Answer (score 15):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

#### Code:

```
nOt/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/z79E////aGMdBRMdBV1TIDaLBQA)

#### Explanation

```
n     # Square each element of the input
 O    # Sum all elements
  t   # Take the square root of the sum
   /  # Divide each element by the square root of the sum
```

Comment: n0t what I expected /

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), 31 bytes

```js
a=>a.map(n=>n/Math.hypot(...a))
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>a.map(n=>n/Math.hypot(...a))

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([20]          ))) // -> [1]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([-5]          ))) // -> [-1]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([-3, 0]       ))) // -> [-1, 0]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([5.5, 6, -3.5]))) // -> [0.62, 0.68, -0.40]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([3, 4, -5, -6]))) // -> [0.32, 0.43, -0.54, -0.65]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([0, 0, 5, 0]  ))) // -> [0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 10):

## Mathematica, 9 bytes

```
Normalize
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y@/KDcxJ7Mq9X9AUWZeiUNadLWRQW0sF5yna4rCM9ZRQJE21TPVUTDTUdA11kNRaKxjoqNrqqNrhixoANSso2AKNuI/AA)

Comment: Or `#/Norm@#&` for the same byte count.

Answer (score 9):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 8 bytes

```
%+/&.:*:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WSkFVW19Nz0rLCshTMDLgSlOINwURxgogtqmeqYIZkKMHEjNWMAFKKsSbAdkGQGiqYAAA)

6 bytes `%|@j./` works [if the vector is at least 2-dimensional](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149169/74681).

Comment: Love the way of getting the magnitude.

Comment: @cole 1 byte longer: `%1%:@#.*:`

Comment: Could you please add an explanation for the uninitiated in J?

Comment: % (divide by) +/ (sum) &.: (under) *: (square). + sums two things. +/ sums a list of things. &.: modifies the preceding operation by applying the following operation first and its inverse afterwards. % normally takes two arguments, but (% f) is a function from x to x % (f x). Most operators automagically work on lists.

Comment: And by the same principles, the function that “normalizes” a vector by adding such a number to each component that they sum to zero is “- +/ % #”.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>5</s> 3 bytes

```
÷ÆḊ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w9sNtD3d0/f//P9pYR8FER0HXFIjNYgE), or see the [test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w9sNtD3d0/T/cfnhZkZGKyqOmNf//RxsZxOooROuagkljHQUw11TPVEfBTEdB11gPLAEUNwHygIK6ZiC@AVCdjoIpSDUA)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to miles!

Comment: 3 bytes with `÷ÆḊ`

Comment: @miles Huh, never knew about that builtin. Thanks

Comment: unfortunately that built-in gives +ve mod for scalars per TIO examplelike absolute value .. the problem requested keeping the sign

Answer (score 6):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 13 bytes

```matlab
@(x)x/norm(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0KzQj8vvygXyPifphFtrKNgoqOgawrEZrEKmv8B)

Answer (score 6):

## C,  <s>73</s>  70 bytes

*Thanks to @Christoph for saving a byte!*

```
s,i;f(v,n)float*v;{for(s=0;i++<n;)s+=*v**v++;for(;--i;)*--v/=sqrt(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7NboMwEITvPMUKqZJ/KeHv4vAkUQ6I1pElAil2fEG8eumCox4ge7J35tuZVt7adlmsMEoTL3qqu6FxzKtJDyOxdaoM5@deUctr5hnznKtVUVIaRZmU/rO2P6Mjlqp58YP5AvdtHdnOAPMCTO@gp9EUAU7IUOE9jEBW1WAKGAwBzg3dtHUeI4qaxB9JpiEW/mKuL/LxdJbEMf7mKFov3BvTk/@MLXptcbpcoYYpS@fAbc02QcAJ6Z09C3ZZ7u3ZW3v@sucCDgG4y45EEYgyKQVUAmSeHKIKAfkRLAOIV1GXSMtqD@KyOIJVAFOsKKB8U7QK2Lz8trprbnaR3f0P)

Comment: +1. `s=0,i=0` instead of `s=i=0` saves one

Comment: I love the use of `s[-i]`but sadly `*--v/=sqrt(s);` is 1 byte shorter.

Comment: @xanoetux Thanks, but I need to initialize the variables inside the function, because [functions need to be reusable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4939/do-function-submissions-have-to-be-reusable). Besides, as global variables, `s` and `i` are automatically initialized to 0. (Turns out I don't need to initialize `i` in the function, because the function always leaves it at value 0)

Comment: @Christoph Thanks! I was initially printing the values from the function, so I needed `v[-i]` to get the values in correct order.

Answer (score 4):

## Python, <s>47</s> 46 bytes

```
lambda v:[e/sum(e*e for e in v)**.5for e in v]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHMKjpVv7g0VyNVK1UhLb9IIVUhM0@hTFNLS88UwY39X1CUmVeikaYRbayjYKKjoGsKxGaxmpr/AQ)

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 9 bytes

```julia
normalize
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/zTYvvyg3MSezKvV/QVFmXklOnkaaRrSRQaymJheSgK4puoCxjgK6IlM9Ux0FMx0FXWM9dOVA1SZACaC8rhmalAHQIB0FU4hx/wE)

Answer (score 3):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 9 bytes

```
{_:mhzf/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWBf7vzreKjejKk2/9r@qVcH/aCODWK5oXVMQYawAYpvqmSqYKega64HEjBVMFHRNFXTNgGwDBQMFU6ASAA)

#### Explanation

```
_    e# Duplicate input.
:mh  e# Fold hypothenuse-length over the vector. This gives the norm, unless the vector
     e# has only one component, in which case it just gives that component.
z    e# Abs. For the case of a single negative vector component.
f/   e# Divide each vector component by the norm.
```

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, 6 bytes

```
Ans/√(sum(Ans2
```

Run with `{1,2,3}:prgmNAME`, where `{1,2,3}` is the vector to be normalized.

Divides each element in the vector by the square root of the sum of the squares of its elements.

Comment: We got the same answer!

Comment: @kamoroso94 Whoops! Didn't see yours when I posted this. If you want to add the explanation from this to your answer I'll delete this.

Comment: Nah I'll just remove mine.  You put more effort into your answer :P

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 23 bytes

```r
function(v)v/(v%*%v)^.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NMs0xfo0xVS7VMM07P9H@aRrKGoaWOkYGm5n8A)

`v%*%v` computes the dot product of v with itself.
The function will issue a warning for length 2 or greater vectors.

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 57 bytes

```java
v->v.stream().map(x->x/v.stream().reduce(0d,Math::hypot))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHBboMwDL33K6yekg2yah07lA5p0rTTeupx2iGF0IYBiYhBRVO/nQVI1dJNSiL5vWf72cl4w32lRZkl350stKoQMouxGmXO7sLZHyytyxilKv8lDVaCFz2l610uY4hzbgxsuCzhZwZgkKNF312N9Yc0uH5TVisibzskn8MI0peu8aPGFSWUFVyTox8dH66wSiR1LMgi8TYcD6vVodUKKe1C2815cE0bJRMorBNiG8ly//kFvNobOhgDQGGQPC4SGl5CP5iGy8SDqSJggcWe7fWXbKruxU89MSquKevWnqB/B/h0Wc3gchCNe2CMQXP2uG0NioKpGpm2IyB5rSreGoZqHIk01LW5VeYlmYMfwRzu4TYpZVzrvD0X46b/lb6UlQwYodTZPHW/)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 10 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @Adám*

*2 bytes saved thanks to @ngn*

```apl
⊢÷.5*⍨+.×⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHXYsOb9cz1XrUu0JDW//wdCCtCZRRMDLgSlM4tN4UTBorgHimeqYKZiCeHkjUWMEEJA/EZgA)

**How?**

```apl
⊢  ÷  .5*⍨  +.  ×⍨
u  ÷    √   Σ   u²
```

Comment: Train for less: `⊢÷.5*⍨(+/×⍨)`

Comment: @Adám thanks alot! I've been trying for hours, couldn't get any train to work

Comment: We should do something about that, as it is really not so hard. When you have a monadic function (other than the rightmost one), begin a parenthesis to its left (or use a `∘` if it isn't derived). Other than that, just swap `⍺` and `⍵` for `⊣` and `⊢`: `{⍵÷.5*⍨+/×⍨⍵}` → `{⍵÷.5*⍨(+/(×⍨⍵))}` → `⊢÷.5*⍨(+/(×⍨⊢))` → `⊢÷.5*⍨(+/(×⍨))` → `⊢÷.5*⍨(+/×⍨)`

Comment: `(+/×⍨)` -> `+.×⍨`

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
t2&|/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8RIrUb///9oYx0FEx0FXVMgNosFAA)

I'm not entirely sure this is the shortest way to do this. First, we duplicate the input, then select the second output type of `|` (which is either `abs`, `norm` or `determinant`). Finally, we divide the input by the norm.

Alternative for 7 bytes:

```
t2^sX^/
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 29 bytes

```hs
f x=map(/sqrt(sum$(^2)<$>x))x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYs9D8IgGIT/yjt0gOQFSSsdGsti4ubkSNCQSD9iS2vBpP8eMS733F3uBhtebppS6mBvZ7uSQ3hvkYTPXJB7SU@F2ind02xHDy30Lp4XH52PAZRqIR@uDyDrNvoIHDqahWzOPqFp4BZz3QNToPVlWmw0hiatS8GFQc3kHxX@ILnEGlnFZQ4VHpFJZHX2AgXKPDFf)

Or for 1 byte more pointfree: `map=<<flip(/).sqrt.sum.map(^2)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 42 bytes

```
a=>(d=a::map)(c=>c/d(b=>b^2)::reduce@+^.5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678n2b7P9HWTiPFNtHKKjexQFMj2dYuWT9FI8nWLinOSNPKqig1pTQ51UE7Ts9U839BUWZeiUaaRrWxjomOrqmOrlmtpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## C++ (gcc), 70 bytes

Input by `std::valarray<float>`. Overwrites the original vector.

```cpp
#import<valarray>
int f(std::valarray<float>&a){a/=sqrt((a*a).sum());}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzLCoMwEEXX5isGS8tM0XbRx8LXvwyxKQFN0hgLRfx2G4XuurhwuY8jncufUi7LTvfO@lC9uWPv@dMIbQIoHEJbFL@wUp3l0ByYJj7Xw8sHRD4ynYaxR6Jyjhgju7F9QCXjU9tGbJyetUESk0j@8aDlwFDDdMngmkF@i7rPpUgUrg2tznrAbQ0aiu1A4HxkK0z3CtIMdNzNyxc)

Comment: I am just lurking codegolf every now and then, but isn't this invalid C++, given "#import", which is a Microsoft specific extension?

Comment: @phresnel `#import` works at least with GCC, Clang and MinGW, too. But, yeah, it's not standard C++.

Comment: @phresnel I forgot to specify gcc. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 5 bytes

```
D²Σ¬/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr/3@XQpnOLD63R//8/2lhHwURHQdcUiM1iAQ)

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 69 bytes

```
(lambda(v)(mapcar(lambda(x)(/ x(sqrt(loop as y in v sum(* y y)))))v))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ncg7EoAgEATRq0zmrIkkHmjVhCp@glJwetTAzl7vzpY0mLINFzjo1G@Hsgq9pl3zP5pwQWM580UXY4IWdNiAinJ7zi@6fFWRMdHAYIV5PR4)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
²∑√/
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuIsiLCIiLCLCsuKIkeKImi8iLCIiLCJbNS41LCA2LCAtMy41XSJd)

```
²    # Square each
 ∑   # Sum
  √  # Square root
   / # Divide by that
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
´(Ṁ/√ṁ□
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv5/aFtusM6jpsb/h7ZoPNzZoP@oY9bDnY2Ppi38//9/dLSRQaxOtK4piDDWAbFN9Ux1zHR0jfVAYsY6Jjq6pjq6ZkC2gY6BjilQSSwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>39</s> 35 bytes

```
->v{v.map{|x|x/v.sum{|x|x*x}**0.5}}
```

-4 bytes thanks to G B.

Comment: Save some bytes by using `sum{...}` instead of `map{...}.sum`

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 51+64=115 bytes

```cs
v=>v.Select(d=>d/Math.Sqrt(v.Select(x=>x*x).Sum()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZJNT@MwEIbPya8YbjYk3tIPLmkiIQSrlQAhFbGH1R7SZAqWXHvxRyiq@tvLJCUVVL3tJda88jvP65lULq2MxW1wUj/D7N15XGbx10pcGaWw8tJoJ36iRiurgxu3Ur9mcaVK5@BhHTtfelnBTdDV9FY6P61NmCssEvh1rcMSbUlVLxZwb@yyVNLhE1GMhRy2TV40YoYtltV5Uf@4K/2LmL1az/b6Ki9WpysuZmHJOOfbLO7BjZE13JVSMx6v4@iKghuF4reVHikqsid6w@L9gMs0vsHXuLCGIWwSOKKfw4bz7H9aj5Jxkk6S9OI4YCBGw4S@41EC6UBMxt1xMdlxN/unzo1RcJz5rWPTacl3DK7@kYx1N6WmtGDRBeVpAYe9dnYuHk3bgFGEOJILYDsD/SFBkwon@b5nr/E4iiz6YDUsSuWwdS5oyUxqD5JQg4yO6WfA3kXa2RlZKVfH6dZ/OXefwD/yL6R7FFUcCjjHdNjSDnARDauXvA3YTm@z/QA)

+64 bytes for the `using System;using System.Collections.Generic;using System.Linq;`

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 94+13=107 bytes

```cs
v=>{var m=0d;foreach(var x in v)m+=x*x;for(int i=0;i<v.Length;)v[i++]/=Math.Sqrt(m);return v;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVFNT4NAED3DrxhvYAHpl5ctTYyJXtSYNKmHpgcKU7vJsqu7C7Zp@tvrQKGaxosXlje7896bN5kJM6XxWBou32G2MxYL5v5G0b0SAjPLlTTRI0rUPLt48cTlJ3MzkRoDr3vX2NTyDB5KmU1yVa4ELpYBdH9TeFG6SAU3OCdapSGBY5VM91WqoUjinK3JUJptvLqwBS6h8otesr3e1jcelxZ4EjM@qaInlO92w/xqwXu95U3ynNpNNPvU1it8ptGWmprZ4cjczlSleA7PKZee7@5d556GUgKjN80t0hjozWm@9e7Coifxa7GEPQxyOATQoT4h32f/phnmwSgIx0F4@4ssjoaDgL6jYQBhHI1HzXE7PkkczhOslBLwN30XMVQN/skccPtBJcyboetcNZpSWIr@kuPUSoquw9fgnd61QcNVcmZqS77rOG3Q61QYrPtoS3BaE/HHjI5J66hbGNC6qJO8NCLN2u5WplVb8CWEZyFCPkyhj@GgFrtQcyiYrmR1iXVSh@M3)

+13 bytes for `using System;`

The non-Linq approach

#### DeGolfed

```cs
v=>{
    var m=0d;
    foreach (var x in v)
        m+=x*x;

    for (int i=0; i < v.Length;)
        v[i++] /= Math.Sqrt(m);

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 45 + 1 (`-a`) = 46 bytes

```perl
say$_/sqrt eval join'+',map"($_)**2",@F for@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIlXr@4sKhEIbUsMUchKz8zT11bXSc3sUBJQyVeU0vLSEnHwU0hLb/Iwe3/f2MFEwVdUwVds3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6yYCAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 10 bytes

9 bytes of code, +1 for `-p` flag.

```
g/RT$+g*g
```

Takes the vector as separate command-line arguments. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/XT8oREU7XSv9////ugX/TfVM/5v91zXWMwUA)

#### How it works

```
      g*g  Arglist, multiplied by itself itemwise
    $+     Sum
  RT       Square root
g/         Divide arglist itemwise by that scalar
           Result is autoprinted (-p flag to format as list)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
cR.aQ
```

Try it online: [Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=cR.aQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B20%5D%0A%5B-5%5D%0A%5B-3%2C%200%5D%0A%5B5.5%2C%206%2C%20-3.5%5D%0A%5B3%2C%204%2C%20-5%2C%20-6%5D%0A%5B0%2C%200%2C%205%2C%200%5D&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
cR.aQQ   implicit Q at the end
c        divide
 R   Q   each element of the input
  .aQ    by the L2 norm of the input vector
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 25 bytes

```
{$_ »/»sqrt sum $_»²}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYo7DsIwFASvMooiKhwszHOTz1UiClwRATYUUZRL0brzxYxxs9LM7PPm7zYvKwfHmLd2JsVTiuHl34TPQjunmL577gnXlab0cWJzxe8N7uEZzno6Miipa6gknWBRpqvWcEEJyv5Bo5Hy6vMP)

`$_`, the list argument to the function, is divided elementwise (`»/»`) by the square root of the sum of the squares of the elements (`»²`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 40 bytes

```
x->map((/)$(?,sum(map(t->t*t,x))**.5),x)
```

I have no idea what I'm doing...

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYqxCsMgGITn9ilu6KDya0NTMwRqHyTtUAKC0GhIDDj03a263N13d3OYgz9itnjglZM0y2dl7Mov7En7sbCKUZooIiXOhVCal5Bt2JDgPKZb9yZMUjftCQ210oSBIHvVhtLfC5VSDpW78iPo@h7Pp4Sfga3ydXusvm7Ox/wH)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `D`, \$ 5 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.12 bytes

```
2^St/
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSi1LsgqWlJWm6FkuN4oJL9CFsqNCCddHGOgomOgq6pkBsFgsRBQA)

##### Explanation

```python
2^St/  # D flag duplicates the input
2^     # Square each
  S    # Sum this list
   t   # Push the square root
    /  # Divide the input by this number
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
Đ²Ʃ√/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIRDm46tfNQxS////2hjHQUTHQVdUyA2iwUA)

##### Explanation

```
Đ²Ʃ√/     implicit input
Đ²        duplicate and square
  Ʃ       sum
   √      square root
    /     divide
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL NARS 12 Characters

```
f←{⍵÷√+/⍵*2}
```

Comment: You don't have to count `f←`  in your byte count, since you can use the dfns without it. By the way, is `√` a single byte in NARS? I'm not familiar with it, so just asking

Comment: @Uriel Nars Apl in the few I know would write with Unicode so number of bytes should be 12x2

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 38 bytes

```
L?!*,EL2@xa@pBcB`s0.5^VcALG$xVcGa@BcB/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/9/HXlFLx9XHyKEi0aHAKdkpodhAzzQuLNnRx12lIizZPdEBKKj///9/4/8m/3VN/@uaAQA)

Answer (score 0):

## Google Sheets, 65 bytes

```
=ArrayFormula(TextJoin(",",1,If(A:A="","",A:A/Sqrt(Sumsq(A:A)))))
```

The input list is in column `A` with one entry per cell. This is how spreadsheets would normally use lists. Unfortunately, this would normally result in a long list of `,0,0,0,0,0,....` at the end so we have to ignore those with the `If Blank then Blank else Math` logic.

If it was all in one cell, instead, the solution would be 95 bytes:

```
=ArrayFormula(TextJoin(",",1,If(Split(A1,",")="","",Split(A1,",")/Sqrt(Sumsq(Split(A1,","))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 6 bytes

```
®/Ux²q
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=ri9VeLJx&input=WzMsIDQsIC01LCAtNl0=)

---

### Explanation

Map over the input array (`®`), divide (`/`) the current element by the square root (`q`) of the sum (`x`) of the elements in the input (`U`) squared (`²`).

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 4, 44 bytes

```
{a in a.map{$0/sqrt(a.reduce(0){$0+$1*$1})}}
```

Recalculates the vector norm for every component, but at least it's terse!

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 47 bytes

```
#(for[i %](/ i(Math/sqrt(apply +(map * % %)))))
```

This version calculates the norm only once and should look a bit more obscure for non-clojurists (`%` is the input argument):

```
#(map / %(repeat(Math/sqrt(apply +(map * % %)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 25 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes a number vector input from range `[1:1]` and outputs the normalized vector to the same range

```vb
[1:1]=[1:1/SumSQ(1:1)^.5]
```